# How to specify the source IP address on curl?

Tags: linux, curl

My server has 5 different external IPs (all working)

I added them by using:

```
 ip addr add xx.xx.xx.xx/32 dev eth0
 ip addr add yy.yy.yy.yy/32 dev eth0
 ip addr add zz.zz.zz.zz/32 dev eth0
```

How can I should `curl` to use either zz.zz.zz.zz IP address?

Comment: How to specify the target website IP address on curl?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
curl --interface zz.zz.zz.zz http://example.com/
```

Comment: Very strange things: it works sometimes (and curl the result)  and mostly of time it says: could not bind to zz.zz.zz.zz

Comment: According to the man page the `--interface` option can take an `interface name, IP address or host name`. https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl I haven't noticed issues with not working properly sometimes.

Comment: Also this is useful to send request from all available ipv6 addresses: `ip -6 addr show dev eth0 | grep 2604 | awk '{print $(NF-2)}' | rev | cut -c 4- | rev | xargs -I % curl -6 'https://api64.ipify.org?format=json' --interface %`

Comment: @yarek To solve the "could not bind to ..." problem, you must add the parameter --ipv4, for example: curl --interface --ipv4  zz.zz.zz.zz http://example.com/